# Hidden objects in old scene?

Tags: objects, blend-files

I've got this old blender scene, last worked on it in 7.78 and I've opened it in 2.8 now to try and clean it up a bit. Basically, I've deleted most of the objects, as there were loads of instances and kept just one of each object.

After doing this the scene file size increased instead of dropping and I can't see any other objects in the scene, apart for the ones I kept. I've unhidden everything, all the collections (former layers).

The problem is, if I want to append objects from this scene into another, I see a huge list of objects and instances. I can also see them in Orphan Data or Blender File data, in the original scene, but I can't seem to be able to select and delete them. I'm getting a 'Not Yet Implemented' error.

Does anyone have an idea of why this happens?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All sorted. In Orphan Data (the Outliner) I found the 'Purge' button which deleted everything I didn't need.